# Finding the orthogonal projection of two polynomial vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

I have two polynomial vectors:

$p$ = $x^2$ - $x$

$q$ = $-2x^2$ + $2x$ + $1$

The inner product of this vector space is defined as:

$$(p, q) = \int_{-1}^1 pq \,dx$$

I need to find the orthogonal projection of $p$ on $q$. I know how to do this with vectors containing numerical/integer values, but not sure how to do it with polynomial vectors. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: All you need to do is remember that the orthogonal projection of $p$ onto $q$ is $(p,q) q / \|q\|$. The magnitude of $q$ can be determined by dotting $q$ with itself then taking the square root.

Comment: For starters, calculate $(p,q)$ and $(q,q)$.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal projection of $p$ onto $q$ is the unique vector $tq$ such that
$$
                    \langle p-tq,q\rangle = 0 \\
                       \langle p,q\rangle-t\langle q,q\rangle = 0 \\
                     t=\frac{\langle p,q\rangle}{\langle q,q\rangle}.
$$
So the orthogonal projection of $p$ onto $q$ is
$$
                 \frac{\langle p,q\rangle}{\langle q,q\rangle}q
$$